# Remove objects/fields which contains a specific word

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON file; I want to remove all of the fields or objects, whose names are a specific word (lets say "test") and then return the stripped JSON file back; how can I do it in Node.JS?

Here is an example of my JSON file:

```
{
    "name": "name1",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "storage": {
        "db": {
            "test": "STRING",
            "tets2": "STRING",

        },
        "test": {
            "test11": "STRING",
            "test2": {
                "test3": "0",
                "test4": "0"
            },
            "test5": {
                "test6": "0",
                "test7": "0"
            }
        },
        "test8": {
            "test9": "STRING",
            "test10": "STRING"
        }
    }
}
```

The desired output:

```
{
    "name": "name1",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "storage": {
        "db": {            
            "tets2": "STRING",
        },        
        "test8": {
            "test9": "STRING",
            "test10": "STRING"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the folloiwng, but I dont know how to use typeof() and check if it is an objectgo deeper in the tree! could you please help me in this regard

```
var new_json = config;

async.each(Object.keys(config), function(key) {

    if (key == "test") {
        delete new_json[key];
    }

    while (typeof (new_json[key]) == "object") {
        // How can I handle it here

    }
});
console.log("done!");
```

Comment: All of the "fields or objects" ... well, which is it? Do you want to remove the properties called "test" from all objects, or do you want to remove objects that contain a property "test"?

Comment: I want to remove from the JSON file, all fields or objects, whose names are "test"; now I included the desired output; the tricky point is "," when we remove an object whose name is "test"...

Comment: You can over the object properties either using a `for-in` loop or using `Object.keys` function and then check if the property is what you are looking for, perhaps using a regex, and if so, delete the property from the object using the `delete` statement.

Comment: Sorry if I posted my question without my attempt; now I have mentioned my attempt and I was wondering if you could help me with that! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should do it:

```
function clean(obj,target) {
    var tmpobj = obj;
    for (var key in tmpobj) {
        if (key === target) {
            delete obj[key];
        }
        else if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            obj[key] = clean(obj[key],target); 
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

called this way:

```
json_struct = clean(json_struct,"test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Recursion code will work. But you need to list of acceptable fields or not acceptable fields and based on  that you need to change the below condition IF you know not acceptable fields then use below conditions.

```
unAcceptableFields.indexOf(key) > 0



var acceptableFields = ["name","version","storage","db", "test9", "test10","tets2", "test8", "test9", "test10" ];
console.log(removeUnwantedFields(testObject, acceptableFields));

function removeUnwantedFields(jsData,acceptableFields) {
    var key;
    if (jsData) {
        for (key in jsData) {           
            if (acceptableFields.indexOf(key) == -1) {
                delete jsData[key];
            }
            else if(typeof jsData[key] === "object"){
              jsData[key] = removeUnwantedFields(jsData[key],acceptableFields);
            }
        }
    }
    return jsData;
}
```

Refer this URL http://jsfiddle.net/55x2V/

Comment: The file is dynamic; the mentioned example was just an example! this code even does not work for that specific example either!